# How to report a rolling distribution to Dataflow

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

I want to report a [Distribution metric](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#metrics) to Dataflow from Beam. I'm able to get the data but I realised that the distribution keep precedent values forever. I'm using a streaming pipeline and I'm much more interested by a rolling distribution only taking into account the last X seconds of data to avoid impacting the mean with outliers from several hours ago. Is it something I can achieve with Beam + Dataflow?

I found something similar in the the [bigquery connector beam source](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1f73a04feb0cf8ae985fe27617a11655866d5ad6/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py#L1275) logging data instead of submitting a Metric but it is using an internal Metric class.

[image: min, max and count metric of distribution]

Answer (score 1):

Distribution counters will be merged with previously recorded values as you said so currently there's no way to produce a rolling distribution counter (Theoretically you can dynamically generate suffix for the counter according to the time and use that to identify a bucket but this will lead to large amount of user counters being tracked by the backend and it is gonna hurt the pipeline performance since there's no way to clean up the no longer needed ones).

If you only want to get the distribution insight in someway you can consider using stateful dofn to track SUM, COUNT, MAX, MIN of elements with several CombiningValueStates, in that way you can calculate per-window distribution on your own.